# Check if exact substring is in a string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know that somewhere someone asked this question before but I've tried to find an answer without any luck.

I'm trying to find if an exact substring is found in a string.

For example

```
<input class="form-control alphanumeric-chars" />
```

I want to match 'alphanumeric-characters' but if the class name was alphanumeric it won't be a match

I've tried many options like:

```
$('input').filter(function() {
   return $(this).className.includes('alphanumeric-chars');
})
```

Or

```
return $(this).className === 'alphanumeric-chars';
```

Any idea what am I missing?

Comment: Since you're using jQuery, `hasClass` might help. See [here](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/).

Comment: Without jQuery there's also `element.classList.contains("classname")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need of `filter`. Just use the class selector as follow

```
$('input.alphanumeric-chars')
```

Comment: this one much better among all.+1.deleted my answer too

Answer (score 1):

why don't you go for `hasClass()` if you want to do something based on condition!

```
if($(this).hasClass('className')){
  //do some code.
}
else{
  //do else part
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple options if you use jquery :

```
$(this).hasClass('alphanumeric-chars')
```

or if you don't use jquery :

```
this.className.indexOf('alphanumeric-chars') // return -1 if not found, >= 0 if found
```

If you want all input without 'alphanumeric-chars' class you can do this :

```
$('input:not(.alphanumeric-chars)')
```

Comment: Wont work for `fdslajfldsaalphanumeric-charsDoYouGetThis`

Comment: we are in class attribute, it would be safe enough here

Answer (score 0):

There multiple ways to find the class

1. `$('input.alphanumeric-chars')` // select only those input who has       class name "alphanumeric-chars"
2. `$('.alphanumeric-chars')`  // select all element has class name "alphanumeric-chars"
3. `$('[class="alphanumeric-chars"]')` // select all element has class name "alphanumeric-chars"
4. `$('input[class="alphanumeric-chars"]')` // select only those input who has class name  "alphanumeric-chars"
5. `$('input').hasClass('alphanumeric-chars')` // select only those input who has class name  "alphanumeric-chars"